# Error: No matching for call to "set_union"

Tags: c++, stl

I'm working on a algorithm problem([Uva 12096]) today, and I wrote a code with my guiding book. It's just like the code on the book, but an error occured when I compile it: [Error] no matching function for call to 'set_union(, std::set::iterator, , std::set::iterator, std::insert_iterator >)'.

I used diff to find if there's anything different with the code my guidebooks shows, but I couldn't find no difference. Where did I go wrong? How could I fix that?
[Uva 12096](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=835&page=show_problem&problem=3248)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<set>
#include<map>
#include<stack>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define ALL(x) x.begin, x.end()
#define INS(x) inserter(x,x.begin())

typedef set<int> Set;
map<Set, int> IDcache; 
vector<Set> Setcache;

int ID(Set x){
    if(IDcache.count(x))    return IDcache[x];
    Setcache.push_back(x); 
    return IDcache[x] = Setcache.size() - 1;
} 

int main(){
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    while(T--){
        stack<int> s;
        int n;
        cin >> n; 
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            string op;
            cin >> op;
            if(op[0] == 'P')    s.push(ID(Set()));
            else if(op[0] == 'D')   s.push(s.top());
            else{
                Set x1 = Setcache[s.top()]; s.pop();
                Set x2 = Setcache[s.top()]; s.pop();
                Set x;
                if(op[0] == 'U') set_union  (ALL(x1), ALL(x2), INS(x));//Error occured here.
                if(op[0] == 'I') set_intersection   (ALL(x1), ALL(x2), INS(x));//Error also occured here.
                if(op[0] == 'A') {
                    x = x2;
                    x.insert(ID(x1));
                }
                s.push(ID(x));
            }
        cout << Setcache[s.top()].size() << endl;
        }
    cout<<"***"<<endl;  
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, I also had a question when I edit the code. 1. The #include can't show as code block. 2. when I use Ctrl+K to edit the code, it's always discriminated as keyboard shortcuts in Firefox. How could I ban the shortcuts in firefox?

Comment: `x.begin` -> `x.begin()` begin is member function.

Comment: `x.begin`? And please don't use macros to make the code shorter. The code might be shorter, but it will also be harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Thank you, I've figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ALL` macro contains errors, you're missing a couple of parens.

`#define ALL(x) x.begin, x.end()` should be `#define ALL(x) x.begin(), x.end()`.